# Parallels with Windows 10 VM automatically shuts down after 30-40 min

Tags: windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I have `Parallels` on my Macbook Pro. I'm have `Windows 10 VM` inside it and few month ago I noticed that it's shutting down by itself when I'm working in it. It's very annoying so I searched logs and found this one:
[image]

I think it might be related to my issue.

I didn't find any good solution in google..

Any idea?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using and where did you get it from?

Comment: In the VM settings, under “Startup and Shutdown” is “Pause Windows when possible” on? Does this shutdown still occur if you turn it off?

Comment: @NoahL "Pause Windows when possible is off"

Comment: @Mark I'm using "Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation". I installed directly from Parallels free images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the VM itself is timing out. You have an Evaluation Edition only,  the Parallels page says "using an evaluation virtual machine".

The VM is actually from Microsoft.

I cannot find the exact details but from my memory Microsoft evaluation VMs time out after 30 minutes but other google results suggest that could be after the 90 days you are allowed.

Comment: Hm.. when I instaled this VM, first few months I didn't face this issue.. probably it started after 90 days..
Okay but what is the solution? Should I buy windows license? or?

Comment: Yes you need to buy Windows